# What is the use of @PersistenceCreator annotation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I have a User.java class that is Model of User collection.
I want to make a few fields in it as private final but when I am doing so , it shows error "final fields may not have been initialised" but Since I am expecting the fields to be initialised by UserRepository I can't initialise the fields at time of declaration.

---

I tried creating a constructor with all the fields and it works(with out using @PersistenceCreator), then there also a @PersistenceCreator annotation whose use I don't know , according to documentation it declares the annotated constructor as default one but there is no further explanation.
Note that the constructor works with or without annotation.

---

Please explain :
What is the use of @PersistenceCreator annotation.

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private final int id;
    @Field("user_name")
    private final String userName;
    private final String password;
    private final boolean active;
    private final String roles;
    @Field("from_phone_number_id")
    private final String fromPhoneNumberId;
    @Field("access_token")
    private final String accessToken;

    
    @PersistenceCreator
    public User(int id, String userName, String password, boolean active, String roles, String fromPhoneNumberId,
            String accessToken) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.fromPhoneNumberId = fromPhoneNumberId;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spring Data** automatically tries to detect a persistent entity’s constructor to be used to materialize objects of that type, if there is a single static factory method annotated with `@PersistenceCreator` then it is used.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.object-creation)

Comment: Thanks @Khalef. Can you please back your answer using some documentation. Thanks.

Comment: In your example, the User class has several fields that are declared as final. This means that their value can only be set once, and it must be set at the time the object is created. The error "final fields may not have been initialized" is occurring because these fields are not being initialized when the class is first instantiated.

Comment: By using the @PersistenceCreator annotation on the constructor, you are telling the persistence framework (in this case MongoDB) that this constructor should be used when creating instances of the User class from persistence data. This allows you to initialize the final fields with values from the database, and avoid the "final fields may not have been initialized" error.

Comment: It is worth noting that the constructor works with or without the annotation, so it is not strictly necessary to use it. However, including it makes it clear to other developers that this constructor is intended to be used for creating instances of the class from persistence data.